# How to calculate following integral?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Consider $0 < x_{1} < \dots < x_{n} < 1$, we have $H(x)/n- $step-function, such as : $H(x)|_{x\in(x_{j},x_{j+1})} = j/n$. We want to compute following integral : $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} \frac{(H(x) - x)^{2}}{x(1-x)}dx$. We may consider it as a sum  $\displaystyle \sum_{j = 0}^{n} \int_{x_{j}}^{x_{j+1}} \frac{(j/n-x)^2}{x(1-x)}$.

The first problem is: it's easy to compute all integrals form $\displaystyle \int_{x_{j}}^{x_{j+1}} \frac{(j/n-x)^2}{x(1-x)}$, but how to collect them all?

Comment: I don't think you can get rid of the sums in general, unless you just turn them into products inside logarithms, which is (IMO) little to no better.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean that $x_0=0$ and $x_{n+1}=1$.  So
$$\int_{x_j}^{x_{j+1}}\frac{(\frac{j}{n}-x)^2}{x(x-1)}$$
$$=(j/n)^2\log(x_j/x_{j+1})+(j/n-1)^2\log\left(\frac{1-x_{j+1}}{1-x_j}\right)+(x_{j+1}-x_j)$$
This gives us three pieces when we take the sum.  For the first piece,
$$\sum_{j=0}^n(j/n)^2\log(x_j/x_{j+1})=\frac{1}{n^2}\log\left(\prod_{j=1}^n\frac{x_j^{j^2}}{x_{j+1}^{j^2}}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{n^2}\log\left(x_1\prod_{j=2}^nx_j^{2j-1}\right)$$
$$=\log\left(x_1\prod_{j=2}^nx_j^{(2j-1)/n^2}\right)$$

The middle piece is harder but mostly the same idea.  I believe we will get this:
$$\log\left(\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{(1-x_{j+1})^{(j/n-1)^2}}{(1-x_j)^{(j/n-1)^2}}\right)$$
$$=\log\left((1-x_n)^{1/n^2}\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}(1-x_j)^{(2j-2n+1)/n^2}\right)$$

The last piece is just $1$, aka $\log(e)$.  So we could put it all together as
$$\log\left(ex_1(1-x_1)^{(3-2n)/n^2}x_n^{(2n-1)/n^2}(1-x_n)^{1/n^2}\prod_{j=2}^{n-1}x_j^{(2j-1)/n^2}(1-x_j)^{(2j-2n+1)/n^2}\right)$$

I did this quickly so there might be some minor computational errors, but you get the gist.